# Refresh page when javascript alert OK is pressed

Tags: php, refresh

```
    function myFunction() 
    {
        var first = confirmDelete(); 
        var second = refreshPage();
        return (first && second);
    }

    function confirmDelete()
    {
        var agree= confirm("confirm?");
        if (agree == true)
            {
            $result = array();
            $result[0] = ('<?php    
                if (isset($_POST['check']))
                {
                    if ($queryType == "apps")
                    {
                        $deletePath = "delete/";
                        include $deletePath.'deleteLastApp.php';
                        include $deletePath.'deleteApp.php';
                    }
                }
                ?>');
            $result[1] = true;
            return $result;
            }
        else
            {
            return false;
            }
    }

    function refreshPage()
    {
        window.location.reload()
    }
```

All this code works perfectly, except the refreshPage function. When the alert "confirm?" is presented and the ok button is pressed, I want the page to reload. Only the cancel button reloads the page. How can I fix this so that only the ok button reloads the page?

Comment: Is this PHP or JavaScript? You made a lot of confusion

Comment: It is Javascript, but as you can see, there is some PHP code embedded in the JS.

Comment: This is JavaScript with PHP nested inside of it...

Comment: When you declare the `$result` array you're using PHP, but the `<?php ?>` tags are missing

Comment: Thank you @Matteo, that is definitely a problem. I recreated the array as a javascript array, but the code still does not work properly.

Comment: Have you checked the console of your browser when you run this code?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try changing your `refreshPage()` function to one of these:

```
function refreshPage()
{
    history.go(0);
}
```

or:

```
function refreshPage()
{
    document.reload()
}
```

Another possible problem might be that you are not calling `refreshPage()` in the right place.

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
function refreshPage()
{
    window.location.reload()
}

function myFunction() 
{
    var first = confirmDelete(); 
    var second = refreshPage();
    return (first && second);
}

function confirmDelete()
{
    var agree= confirm("confirm?");
    if (agree == true)
        {
        $result = array();
        $result[0] = ('<?php    
            if (isset($_POST['check']))
            {
                if ($queryType == "apps")
                {
                    $deletePath = "delete/";
                    include $deletePath.'deleteLastApp.php';
                    include $deletePath.'deleteApp.php';
                }
            }
            ?>');
        $result[1] = true;
        return $result;
        refreshPage();
        }
    else
        {
        return false;
        }
}
```

Notice that i changed the location of the `refreshPage()` block to the top of the page, and i added a call to that function under the `return $result` line.

Make that your complete code, and see if it works!

Comment: Neither of those options works the right way. When the cancel button is pressed, it calls the functions that only the OK button is supposed to call

Comment: Then the problem is _not_ the `refreshPage` function. It is the code that _calls_ the function! I suggest editing your question, as it states: "_All this code works perfectly, except the refreshPage function_"

Comment: Hmm that is true then. If you happen to catch any errors within one of those functions, please let me know. I have a feeling it's an error with the result array.

Comment: Sadly, that did not fix it. Is it possible that my return function is only returning the first result?

Comment: It could be, as it looks like the `reloadPage` function is working properly, so it must be something to do with another function or line.

Comment: Thanks @pattyd. If you don't mind, I'm going to ask another question. How can I reset the agree variable so that at the end of the confirmDelete function it will return to its original value. Right now, it's stuck as true so only the first onClick call works.

Comment: No problem! Yes, just add `agree = false` at the end of that block. Let me know if you need further explanation! :)

Comment: Oddly enough, `agree = false` did not work, but `var agree = false` did. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Interesting! Sometimes little weird things like that happen to me too! I guess that does the same thing though. If I helped out, then don't forget to accept my answer! Thanks!